# play a recorded audio (saved temp storageDirectory) - record_mp3 package

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I record a audio using `record_mp3`: ^3.0.0 ([this](https://pub.dev/packages/record_mp3)) package. Like below, How to play it using `audioplayers` package ([this](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers)).

**Below - How I record audio -**

```
void startRecord() async {
    bool hasPermission = await checkPermission();
    if (hasPermission) {
      statusText = "Recording...";
      recordFilePath = await getFilePath();
      isComplete = false;
      RecordMp3.instance.start(recordFilePath, (type) {
        statusText = "Record error--->$type";
        setState(() {});
      });
    } else {
      statusText = "No microphone permission";
    }
    setState(() {});
  }



void stopRecord() {
    bool s = RecordMp3.instance.stop();
    if (s) {
      statusText = "Record complete";
      isComplete = true;
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

Future<String> getFilePath() async {
    Directory storageDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String sdPath = storageDirectory.path + "/record";
    var d = Directory(sdPath);
    if (!d.existsSync()) {
      d.createSync(recursive: true);
    }
    return sdPath + "/test_${i++}.mp3";
  }
```

**after recording it, I want to play it. I used this method, (They given in example)**

```
void play() {
    if (recordFilePath != null && File(recordFilePath).existsSync()) {
      AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
      audioPlayer.play(recordFilePath, isLocal: true);
    }
  }
```

Now, It's not valid. show syntax error

- The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Source'
- The named parameter 'isLocal' isn't defined.

How to play the audio I have recorded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can play it like this,

```
void play() async {
    if (File(recordFilePath).existsSync()) {
      await audioPlayer.play(DeviceFileSource(recordFilePath));
    }
  }
```